# How to write code VBA for copying all sheets in one sheet excel

Tags: excel, vba

Sheet 1
name amount
abc    25.00
bba    45.00

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()
    Sheets("sheet1").Range("A:B").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet4").Range("a1")
End Sub
```

if I have more than one sheet how should I write instead of (sheet1) to destination file To sheet 4?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()
   dim col as integer
   col = 1
   For Each wks In Worksheets
      if (wks.Name <> "Sheet4") then
          wks.Range("A:B").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, col)
          col = col + 2
      end if
   next wks
End Sub
```

Comment: thanx for your responds but it copies only sheet no 3 i want to be copied sheet1,sheet2,sheet3,(all data to)sheet no 4 i hope you will help me thank you

Comment: My bad, the sheets were always copied at the same destination, explaining why you've got only the last sheet. Look at my edit, it should work now ;)

Comment: error message object is not support this property or method

Comment: An "s" was missing to "Cells" :P

Comment: Hmm... Inversed the col & "1", tested, no error... Should work now :)

Comment: yes coppied on sheet no 1 and an error messege coppy area not same size and shape

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand... I've tested it on Excel with differents infos on sheets, without any problem. Could you execute the script step by step (with F8 key) to localize the problem you have?

Comment: but my each sheet size is different that the problem sheet 1 has 8 rows sheet 2 has 7 rows sheet 3 has 14 rows

Comment: The number of rows in each sheet shoudn't be a problem since we copy the complete 2 first columns of these sheets (the "Range(3a:B")").